# What keeps charge from "spreading" in a CCD pixel?

Tags: solid-state-physics, particle-detectors

In a CCD, you generally have a photosensitive substrate (e.g. n-doped silicon) that is attached to a network of electrodes that, after exposure, will move the charge, allowing the CCD to be "read". The photosensitive substrate is, as I've read, divided into many different "sections" called pixels. Thus, these pixels effectively act as "bins" for systematically gathering information about the distribution of the impinging light.

However, I have read nowhere how exactly the pixels are separated. How does charge generated in the vicinity of a certain "pixel" stay within that pixel? Is there some sort of material between the pixels that separate them? Are the electrodes always turned on during exposure in such a way that they effectively confine nearby particles in a potential well?

Comment: Who says it *does* stay in the same pixel?

Comment: Well I would imagine that because most images I have seen taken by CCDs don't look completely blurred due to the electrons repelling each other (in the case of no confinement), they must be confined in some way. I just don't know exactly how it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert, but Wikipedia has the answer you are looking for.

Essentially, the charge is stored in a capacitor formed by a gate and the silicon.  A voltage is put onto the gate, and an electric field will form in the silicon.  Because of that electric field, charge carriers "generated" from the light hitting the silicon will drift into the field and stay there.

When that happens there will be a corresponding current that flows in the gate side of the capacitor, but the voltage won't change because the voltage source driving the gate will source or sink the current.  So, the charge in the silicon will be trapped there.

The animation on Wikipedia shows that in a CCD that the charge is actually shifted down a row of these capacitors by controlling the voltages across the gate-silicon capacitors.  That's pretty neat, and that is what makes a "Charge Coupled Device" what it is.

So, each pixel would be defined as the region around the gate electrode which is catching the electrons.  I'm sure that during exposure that these gates are biased to a very specific voltage.  But, after exposure, the voltage on these gates would have to be clocked (or periodically switched between two voltages) in a specific way to shift the charge from one gate to the next.

At the end of the chain, probably one for each row of pixels, would be a special amplifier to measure how much charge there is for the pixel. Then the result of the measurement would be stored somewhere.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge-coupled_device#Basics_of_operation

Comment: Ah, that makes sense in my mind. Thanks! (I'm going to wait to see if anybody else has an answer)

Comment: There is a special case of spreading when the light intensity is to high. Some electrons jump to the neighbor pixels.